# on ie, the expression excute twice

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

```
<div style="width:expression(alert('1'));"></div>
```

If you run this code in IE7 it wil excute twice. Why?

Comment: you should avoid using expressions. do whatever you plan to do in JS instead.

Comment: Hum... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: unless you provide some more context, we'll not be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use expressions. Expression parsing engine recalculates them very often for minimal changes in context, including things like mouse movements, changes in every element focus and so on, introducing insane overhead. There's also no clear documentation for every point where that happens, so you often cannot plan ahead for anything slightly more complex than basic calculations. Finally, Microsoft marked them as deprecated so they won't even work in future IE versions.